# External transformer for PCB made for someone else a few volts higher than circuit was designed for, will this damage the optoisolators?

Tags: voltage, opto-isolator

I sold my first PCB to someone for a bowling lane project.

This PCB has 10 opto-isolators(LTV-817) which are connected(after going through a bridge rectifier) to external switches going to a transformer.

When I was designing the board, I had them take a picture of their multimeter which showed 22.4 volts AC. I designed it with this in mind and after considering the voltage drop from the bridge rectifier, I decided on a 1K ohm resistor to be used for each opto-isolator.

I am getting worried now after a unrelated problem with something else and they shared a picture of their multimeter connected to the transformer. This time it shows 25.5 volts AC. The previous reading might have been because something else dropped the voltage down to 22.4 volts.

Would this have damaged the opto-isolators since it is a few volts higher than I designed the circuit for? Should I tell them to get ten 100 ohm resistors to put in line with each wire?

Here is the schematic of one connection, in the actual circuit there are 10 of these with a common side connected together to each bridge rectifier:

[image]

[Here is the data sheet to the opto-isolator I used
.](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811122022_Lite-On-LTV-817_C125120.pdf)

Comment: We will need to see the schematic for your project and you should provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the optoisolators.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Added.

Comment: In the future, if you want to play based on the highest voltage that might be applied, consider requesting open circuit voltage of the transformer in question.  If you rectified with a capacitor on the output I assume you planned your resistor based on peak rather than RMS ac voltage?

Comment: Next time you can calculate what your circuit will do with a 25.5V supply voltage, and then you can see whether it's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LTV817 is good for up to 50mA through the LED, so there should be no problem with 22mA (ballpark) instead of your designed 20mA.

The LED will age slightly faster but if the switches are normally open momentary switches this is unlikely to be significant.

Line voltage is not constant and thus ac supplies produced using a transformer also vary so it is good practice to allow for some variation in the supply voltage.